# Can I create a verilog file to both simulate and synthesize?

Tags: fpga, verilog, simulation, synthesis

Recently I was reading a Verilog study book. I finally realized that a Verilog file may not be synthesizable, because some Verilog statements are for simulation use only. But I'm too lazy to make one file to create a module and another to simulate it. Can I mix both up in the same file, and if so, how?

Comment: I like this question because I too am too lazy too make two files. How come the designers of the language didn't anticipate this?

Comment: Oh dear, I will be sad hearing this fact.Nevertheless, Is it a good hobit to put these file apart? @dextorb

Comment: Yes, I believe best practice is to create both synthesis and simulation files for your modules.

Comment: Do you mean that you do not want to put your test bench in a separate file? You can always have two modules in a file and prevent one from being considered for synthesis with pragmas (or commenting it out...). What tool are you using? Many can generate test bench skeletons for you that take a lot of the busy work out of it.

Answer (score 3):

Most synthesis tools support pragmas. For example, in the following code, the and gate will not be considered for synthesis.

```
// synthesis translate_off
    and2 (a, b, c[4]);
// synthesis translate_on
```

Also, predefined macros can also be used:

```
`ifdef synthesis
 parameter PARAM = 4;
`endif
```

Both of the above are tool specific, so you'll have to see which predefined macros your tool supports, or you could define a macro yourself and use that.

If you'd like something more robust and not as tool specific, you can use a conditional generate statement that nicely splits simulation and synthesis:

```
generate
if (SYNTHESIS == 1)
ff_for_synthesis_here
else
ff_for_simulation_here
end generate
```